# Plot a fourier transform of a sin wav with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy, fft, continuous-fourier

I am trying to plot a fourier transform of a sign wave based on the [scipy documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/fft.html#d-discrete-fourier-transforms)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.fft

def sinWav(amp, freq, time, phase=0):
    return amp * np.sin(2 * np.pi * (freq * time - phase))

def plotFFT(f, speriod, time):
    """Plots a fast fourier transform

    Args:
        f (np.arr): A signal wave
        speriod (int): Number of samples per second
        time ([type]): total seconds in wave
    """

    N = speriod * time
    # sample spacing
    T = 1.0 / 800.0
    x = np.linspace(0.0, N*T, N, endpoint=False)

    yf = scipy.fft.fft(f)
    xf = scipy.fft.fftfreq(N, T)[:N//2]
    plt.plot(xf, 2.0/N * np.abs(yf[0:N//2]))
    plt.grid()
    plt.xlim([1,3])
    plt.show()


speriod = 1000
time  = {
    0: np.arange(0, 4, 1/speriod),
    1: np.arange(4, 8, 1/speriod),
    2: np.arange(8, 12, 1/speriod)
}

signal = np.concatenate([
    sinWav(amp=0.25, freq=2, time=time[0]),
    sinWav(amp=1, freq=2, time=time[1]),
    sinWav(amp=0.5, freq=2, time=time[2])
])   # generate signal

plotFFT(signal, speriod, 12)
```

---

**Desired output**

I want to be getting a fourier transform graph which looks like this

[image]

**Current output**

But instead it looks like this

[image]

---

**Extra**

This is the sin wave I am working with

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.fft

def sinWav(amp, freq, time, phase=0):
    return amp * np.sin(2 * np.pi * (freq * time - phase))

def plotFFT(f, speriod, time):
    """Plots a fast fourier transform

    Args:
        f (np.arr): A signal wave
        speriod (int): Number of samples per second
        time ([type]): total seconds in wave
    """

    N = speriod * time
    # sample spacing
    T = 1.0 / 800.0
    x = np.linspace(0.0, N*T, N, endpoint=False)

    yf = scipy.fft.fft(f)
    xf = scipy.fft.fftfreq(N, T)[:N//2]

    amplitudes = 1/speriod* np.abs(yf[:N//2])
  
    plt.plot(xf, amplitudes)
    plt.grid()
    plt.xlim([1,3])
    plt.show()


speriod = 800
time  = {
    0: np.arange(0, 4, 1/speriod),
    1: np.arange(4, 8, 1/speriod),
    2: np.arange(8, 12, 1/speriod)
}

signal = np.concatenate([
    sinWav(amp=0.25, freq=2, time=time[0]),
    sinWav(amp=1, freq=2, time=time[1]),
    sinWav(amp=0.5, freq=2, time=time[2])
])   # generate signal

plotFFT(signal, speriod, 12)
```

You should have what you want. Your amplitudes were not properly computed, as your resolution and speriod were inconsistent.

[image: Output]

Longer data acquisition:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.fft

def sinWav(amp, freq, time, phase=0):
    return amp * np.sin(2 * np.pi * (freq * time - phase))

def plotFFT(f, speriod, time):
    """Plots a fast fourier transform

    Args:
        f (np.arr): A signal wave
        speriod (int): Number of samples per second
        time ([type]): total seconds in wave
    """

    N = speriod * time
    # sample spacing
    T = 1.0 / 800.0
    x = np.linspace(0.0, N*T, N, endpoint=False)

    yf = scipy.fft.fft(f)
    xf = scipy.fft.fftfreq(N, T)[:N//2]

    amplitudes = 1/(speriod*4)* np.abs(yf[:N//2])
  
    plt.plot(xf, amplitudes)
    plt.grid()
    plt.xlim([1,3])
    plt.show()


speriod = 800
time  = {
    0: np.arange(0, 4*4, 1/speriod),
    1: np.arange(4*4, 8*4, 1/speriod),
    2: np.arange(8*4, 12*4, 1/speriod)
}

signal = np.concatenate([
    sinWav(amp=0.25, freq=2, time=time[0]),
    sinWav(amp=1, freq=2, time=time[1]),
    sinWav(amp=0.5, freq=2, time=time[2])
])   # generate signal

plotFFT(signal, speriod, 48)
```

[image: Output]

Comment: It should look like that graph I posted where the amplitude is 3.5, at freq 2

Comment: Why doesn't this work with other sampling rates? Shouldn't the freqencies be independent of the sampling rate? I thought the sr just determined the size along the x axis that the signal was split into

Comment: Well, if you're working on continuous data you're right (so in maths). But in physics, data are not continuous. And FFT refers to Discrete FT, in that specific physical context. The reason for my changes can be found here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist_frequency
It is all about this relationship. In fact, your shift is due to spectrum "folding" cause you're not enough in line with the Nyquist relation.

Comment: I'm trying to make my graph look more continuous, but I keep getting the same blocky graph

Comment: In other words, I want the x axis split into smaller sections

Comment: Well, you should definitely work on your lectures :). To do that, you need more timepoints. See my edit for changes.

Comment: Wouldn't I just want to increase the `speriod`? So that the time is split into smaller chunks? I've tried doing that, but receive the same results. I also noticed that the updates you just made changed the amplitude values

Comment: Yes sorry I corrected. In fact, amplitudes are calculated as 1/n_samples, with n_samples = speriod * nb_period. So you increase the number of samples, but not the speriod/sampling frequency. As a general rule, the longer your wave in time domain is, the better is the resolution.

Comment: So this doesn't work correctly when I change the freqency of the sin waves(if say I change them to frequency 1 instead of 2)

Comment: I'm learning this on my own. I went through a udemy course and a textbook and it still all seems foreign

Comment: Well, by the way: if you set the freq to 1, the peak is at 1. which is what you expect (1Hz). So it is working :).

Answer (score 0):

You can also interactively plot this. You may need to install the `pip install scikit-dsp-comm`

```py
# !pip install scikit-dsp-comm
# Make an interactive version of the above
from ipywidgets import interact, interactive
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import fftpack

plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = [10, 8]

font = {'weight' : 'bold',
        'size'   : 14}
plt.rc('font', **font)


def pulse_plot(fm = 1000, Fs = 2010):
    tlen = 1.0  # length in seconds
    # generate time axis
    tt = np.arange(np.round(tlen*Fs))/float(Fs)
    # generate sine
    xt = np.sin(2*np.pi*fm*tt)
    plt.subplot(211)
    plt.plot(tt[:500], xt[:500], '-b')
    plt.plot(tt[:500], xt[:500], 'or', label='xt values')
    plt.ylabel('$x(t)$')
    plt.xlabel('t [sec]')
    strt2 = 'Sinusoidal Waveform $x(t)$'
    strt2 = strt2 + ', $f_m={}$ Hz, $F_s={}$ Hz'.format(fm, Fs)
    plt.title(strt2)
    plt.legend()
    plt.grid()
    X = fftpack.fft(xt)
    freqs = fftpack.fftfreq(len(xt)) * Fs
    plt.subplot(212)
    N = xt.size
    # DFT
    X = np.fft.fft(xt)
    X_db = 20*np.log10(2*np.abs(X)/N)
    #f = np.fft.fftfreq(N, 1/Fs)
    f = np.arange(0, N)*Fs/N
    plt.plot(f, X_db, 'b')
    plt.xlabel('Frequency in Hertz [Hz]')
    plt.ylabel('Frequency Domain\n (Spectrum) Magnitude')
    plt.grid()
    plt.tight_layout()
    
    
interactive_plot = interactive(pulse_plot,fm = (1000,20000,1000), Fs = (1000,40000,10));
output = interactive_plot.children[-1]
# output.layout.height = '350px'
interactive_plot
```

[image]

Comment: why is it from -300 to 0?

Comment: @Sam because the y axis is just spectrum magnitude. You can make that linear if you want.

Comment: Shouldn’t it still be 350?